# Zxing Codigos QR android

Tags: java, android, zxing

Estoy siguiendo esta respuesta para la utilizacion de un layout perzonalizado

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627145/zxing-barcode-scanner-in-custom-layout-in-fragment

resumiendo importe todas las bibliotecas

```
maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }

   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
   compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
   compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
   compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
```

Y en mi Clase

```
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegratorCI = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegratorCI.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Lea el codigo QR correspondiente al CashIn");
    scanIntegratorCI.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_layout_rq);
    scanIntegratorCI.initiateScan();
```

Esta todo andando correcto , yo genero un QR con la app puedo leerlo extraer los datos etc , pero el metodo `setCaptureLayout` me aparece como que no existe , y no veo la forma de poder perzonalizar el xml segun la documentacion oficial 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que no se porque no me deja utizar este metodo cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que hay muchas variantes de esa librería:

En el [repositorio original de zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) ese método no existe, pero hay [otro repositorio del usuario martar](https://github.com/martar/zxing-android-minimal/blob/master/zxing-android/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) donde la misma clase **sí** tiene ese método, y parece ser un fork del que tú usas ([journeyapps](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)):

```
/**
     * Change the layout used by the intent.
     *
     * @param intent the scanning intent
     * @param resourceId the layout resource id to use.
     */
    public static void setCaptureLayout(Intent intent, int resourceId) {
        intent.putExtra(CaptureActivity.ZXING_CAPTURE_LAYOUT_ID_KEY, resourceId);
    }
```